# Группировка детей по их родителям

Tags: java

Есть класс:

```
public class Genre {
    private Integer id;
    private Integer parentId;
...
}
```

Есть список объектов в БД:

```
insert into genre (id, name, parent_id, slug)
values (1, 'Drama', 0, 'tonkz');
insert into genre (id, name, parent_id, slug)
values (2, 'Comedy', 0, 'fuihj');
insert into genre (id, name, parent_id, slug)
values (3, 'Crime', 0, 'llzxg');
insert into genre (id, name, parent_id, slug)
values (4, 'Thriller', 0, 'judmp');
insert into genre (id, name, parent_id, slug)
values (5, 'Film-Noir', 4, 'vxqrk');
insert into genre (id, name, parent_id, slug)
values (6, 'Fantasy', 0, 'xmjdj');
insert into genre (id, name, parent_id, slug)
values (7, 'Mystery', 4, 'paekx');
insert into genre (id, name, parent_id, slug)
values (8, 'Documentary', 0, 'arblb');
insert into genre (id, name, parent_id, slug)
values (9, 'Western', 1, 'nizdz');
insert into genre (id, name, parent_id, slug)
values (10, 'Animation', 0, 'onvhb');
```

Я пытаюсь сгруппировать по parent_id, но вместо Integer мне нужно вывести соответствующий этому ID жанр.

```
public Map<Genre, List<Genre>> getGenresMap() {
        Map<Integer, Genre> ids = genreRepository.findAll().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Genre::getId, Function.identity()));

        return genreRepository.findAll().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(genre -> ids.get(genre.getParentId())));
    }
```

Почему у меня выходит ошибка:
java.lang.NullPointerException: element cannot be mapped to a null key и как решить эту задачу?

Вывод из результирующей Map должен быть таким:

```
Drama
   Western
Comedy
Crime
Thriller
   Film-Noir
   Mystery
Fantasy
Documentary
Animation
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что в том случае, если у жанра `parentId = 0`, то из мапы `ids` вы достаете `null`, поскольку у вас нет ни одного жанра с `id = 0`. В таком случае вам надо возвращать не `null`, а сам объект жанра.
Минимальные изменения, необходимые, чтобы заставить ваш код работать, могут выглядеть так:

```
public Map<Genre, List<Genre>> getGenresMap() {
    Map<Integer, Genre> ids = genreRepository.findAll().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Genre::getId, Function.identity()));

    return genreRepository.findAll().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(genre -> Optional.ofNullable(ids.get(genre.getParentId())).orElse(genre)));
}
```

Comment: В данном случае группировка получается неверной. Родитель должен быть в отдельном списке от детей.